# Firefox for Android add-on is disabled in Nightly?

Tags: android, firefox-addon-sdk

I developed a very basic Firefox add-on that uses the `page-mod` module, but I can't get it to work on Firefox for Android (Nightly). It works with Desktop Firefox.
The add-on was pushed correctly to my testing device using `jpm-mobile`, as it shows up in the `about:addons` list, however it is disabled. The "enable" button is also grayed out.
I verified that the `xpinstall.signatures.required` setting in `about:config` is set to false, so that can't be it. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an `engines` section in `package.json`:

```
"engines": {
    "firefox": ">=38.0a1",
    "fennec": ">=38.0a1"
},
```